# Facebook PHP SDK: Cannot get Access Token from JavascriptHelper Class

Tags: php, facebook

I have am using FB's Javascript SDK on the client and PHP SDK on the server.
I can see when I use `getSignedRequest()` I get the signed request containing the `code` property and  the correct userId. However for the life in me I can't figure out how to go on to use this signedRequest to obtain a valid access token which I can use to create further calls for things like user information. I have tried querying for the access code by attempting to instantiate a signed request or calling the ->getAccessToken() method on the $facebook object as well as the `jsHelper` object but nothing is returned to me. Here's my code:

```
require_once 'src/autoload.php';
 $facebook = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $AppId,
   'app_secret' => $AppSecret,
   'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
 ]);


$jsHelper = $facebook->getJavaScriptHelper();
$signedRequest = $jsHelper->getSignedRequest();

if ($signedRequest) {

try {
  $codeField = $signedRequest->get('code');

  $g = $facebook->getAccessToken();
  //I would hope this would be the access token, but sadly it's an empty      
     value.
  error_log($g);

 } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
 error_log("fbResp Ex: ". $e->getMessage());
 exit;
 } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  error_log("SDK Ex: ". $e->getMessage());

  exit;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I never used `JavaScriptHelper` but `AccessToken` comes from `helper` not Facebook object itself. Try

```
 $g = $jsHelper->getAccessToken();
```